# Why does Putin refer to the Ukraine invasion as a 'Special Operation'?

Tags: russian-federation, armed-conflict, ukraine

Putin has several times referred to Russia's occupation of Ukraine as a 'Special Operation' rather than a full fledged war, although it looks to be very much like the latter.

But why does he refer to it as such? Why didn't he declare full scare war on Ukraine? What difference would it have made if he had declared full scale war?

Since it's a special operation for Putin, he didn't commit the full bulk of Russian troops for the Ukrainian invasion. Why didn't he do so?

Comment: It also makes it easier for fence-sitting countries (such as BRICS countries) to continue co-operating with Russia.

Comment: The only person really able to answer this question is only Putin himself, everithing else would be just speculations.

Comment: I think it is how to describe oneself and justify one's act when doing the right thing. I have no idea if Russia is doing the right thing or wrong thing though. It may be right or they may pretend it to be right. No one actually knows. The question of which this question is a duplicate, answers what I said here.

Answer (score -4):

**Full scale war means mobilization - which means removing people from plants, offices and factories and back to armed forces** (Russia do have a one-year mandatory duty for all men above 18 years).

Of course, that would boost military efforts, but it seems, that now, economics is in priority - as [Turn to the East](https://theasanforum.org/tracking-russias-turn-to-the-east-over-a-decade/) is more about economics inside [SCO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shanghai_Cooperation_Organisation)

At the current point, operation is a positional standoff, weakening EU industries, just because it was based on cheap energy. It's not that good, because Russia also have casualties - both military and economical, but way lesser.

Comment: Irrelevant and would say strong claim dropped as the last sentence. It is possible to argue maybe lesser, but way lesser?

Comment: Highlighted core idea.)

Comment: Not my DV, but (going along with your idea) Russia could have turned off gas 20 years ago. That should have ruined the EU and it would have had no money to expand in Ukraine or something.

Comment: Russia wasn't ready twenty years ago. Now - turn to the east is in progress, so it's time. And Europe - 8 centuries of history describes multiple European crusades to the east - no reason to sit and wait another. No aggression - it's just my opinion. And it's logical, I think.